# Color a semiplane, but in the background

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

See the following code which plots a "staircase" line:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$j$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$i$};


\draw[](-4,5)--(-4,-1);
\draw[](-4,-1)--(-2,-1);
\draw[](-2,-1)--(-2,-3);
\draw[](-2,-3)--(2,-3);
\draw[](2,-3)--(2,-4);
\draw[](2,-4)--(5,-4);




\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I want to fill with a light color the upper semiplane bounded by such a line. I also would like the selected area to be on the background, In other words the color shouldn't cover the axes and the  grid. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

I used `\def\myPath` to use it multiple times. I also used it in *one* draw command to make a single path. Using the `backgrounds` library you can draw things 'in the back'. An alternative could of course be to execute the `\fill` command before you draw the grid and the axes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$j$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$i$};

    \def\myPath{(-4,5)
            --(-4,-1)
            --(-2,-1)
            --(-2,-3)
            --( 2,-3)
            --( 2,-4)
            --( 5,-4)}
    \draw \myPath;

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \fill[red!20] \myPath |- cycle;
    \end{scope}



    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The alternative method without using the `backgrounds` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

%\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\myPath{(-4,5)--(-4,-1)--(-2,-1)--(-2,-3)--( 2,-3)--( 2,-4)--( 5,-4)}

        % Filled area
        \fill[red!20] \myPath |- cycle;

        % Grid and axes
        \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
        \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$j$};
        \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$i$};

        % Drawn plot
        \draw \myPath;

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both result in the same image.